# Composer error: no matching package found

Tags: php, git, symfony, composer-php

I have two Symfony projects: project-a (root project) and project-b.

My composer.json file from project-a contains:

```
{
  "name": "myprojects/project-a",
  "require": {
    "myprojects/project-b": "dev-master",
  },
  "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:MYPROJECTS/project-b.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

And my composer.json from project-b:

```
{
  "name": "myprojects/project-b",
  "require": {
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3"
  }
}
```

I need to update project-b but when I execute the command `composer update myprojects/project-b` from project-a, I get this composer error:

> [Composer\DependencyResolver\SolverProblemsException]
>
> Problem 1
>
> - Installation request for myprojects/project-b dev-master -> satisfiable by
>     myprojects/project-b[dev-master].
> - myprojects/project-b dev-master requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.3 -> no matching package found.
>
> Potential causes:
>
> - A typo in the package name
> - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting

I have tried solve this adding `"minimum-stability": "dev"` property to both composer.json files, but it doesn't works.. How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Would https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/861#issuecomment-58867964 help?

Comment: composer clear cache and self-update solves my problem, Thanks!! I'm not using "minimum-stability": "dev" and all worked perfectly.

Comment: OK, I will add an answer later today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented in [guzzle/guzzle issue 861](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/861#issuecomment-58867964):

> Looks like an issue with your caching.
>   Try clearing your composer cache, and self-update composer, then try again.

The [OP Wildchild](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5498428/wildchild) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46979824/composer-error-no-matching-package-found#comment81011921_46979824):

> composer clear cache and self-update solves my problem

`"minimum-stability": "dev"`  is not needed.